# Where do I call setState for redux values?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm pretty new to react native and async programming, and trying to understand how to "sync" redux state values and local state values.

For example, I have a text field "aboutMe" stored server side, and using mapStateToProps to place it into props:

```
   const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return { aboutMe: state.aboutMe };
   }
```

In render, I have a TextInput I'm using so that the user can edit this field, and I would like to default to what is saved on the server side:

```
         <TextInput
          onChangeText={(aboutMe) => { 
              this.setState({aboutMe});
          }}
          value={this.state.aboutMe}
        />
```

Basically, somewhere I need to call

```
      this.setState({ aboutMe: this.props.aboutMe });
```

Where is the right place to this? I was trying to use componentWillReceiveProps, but that lifecycle method is not called on constructor, so I would need to setState twice (in constructor and in componentWillReceiveProps).

Is there another way to do this? I feel like this is a pretty generic problem that a lot of react native developers have solved but I couldn't find a generally accepted way online.

Thanks!

Edit:

I have alot of TextInputs, so I have a separate button to call the action to save the variables:

```
    <Button onPress={()=>{ 
      this.props.saveUserInput(this.state.aboutMe, 
      this.state.name, this.state.address, ....}}>
      <Text> Save changes </Text>
    </Button>
```

From the comments, I understand that it's possible to call the save action onChangeText... but is that too much traffic back and forth? Would it be better to save all of the variables locally to state and then call a save for everything at once? Also, what if the user would like to "cancel" instead of save? The changes would have been already saved and we will not be able to discard changes?

Comment: you do not use setState to modify your store state, instead you should dispatch actions and handle the actions accordingly on your reducers

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. To me it looks like you are changing the value through an action as well as through the input field. So, you need to update it when the redux store value changes AND when the input field changes. Is this correct? Then you should ask yourself why not just change it in the redux store at all times? Or the other way around.

Comment: It seems to me that you can use redux store without component state here. OnMount, dispatch an action to retrieve the server value and onChange dispatch an update of the value in the store. For the value that's rendered, have this controlled by the value in the redux store

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) If your component is a controlled component (you need state in it) and the request is asynchronous indeed you have to set the state in the `componentWillReceiveProps` like this:

```
class ExampleComp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      aboutMe: ""
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      aboutMe: nextProps.aboutMe,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={(aboutMe) => {
          this.setState({aboutMe});
        }}
        value={this.state.aboutMe}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Keep in mind the key here is that the state must remain the single source of truth from now on.

2) The other option would be, you can wait until the request is finished in the parent component and then set the `aboutMe` in your constructor, this way you can avoid `componentWillReceiveProps`. For example:

```
class ParentComp extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.aboutMe && <ExampleComp/>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ExampleComp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      aboutMe: props.aboutMe
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={(aboutMe) => {
          this.setState({aboutMe});
        }}
        value={this.state.aboutMe}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The downside of this is that the text input won't be shown until the request is finished.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have edited your question, it is more clear what you want to achieve, so I want to address that.

You could keep the state of your controlled input elements in the component, then use the redux store to store persistent data and to populate the default values.

```
class Component extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
          aboutMe: props.aboutMe,
          ... // other data
       }
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault() // To prevent redirect

      // Dispatch the save user input action
      this.props.dispatch(saveUserInput(this.state))
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
           <TextInput onTextChange={text => this.setState({...this.state, aboutMe: text}) />
           ... // input fields for other data

           // Clicking this fill trigger the submit event for the form
           <button type="submit">Save</button> 
        </form>
      )
    }
  }
```